# Delete component which is not used but rendered with

Tags: publishing, dynamic-linking, component, renderer

I have a component which is not used in anything but it is published dynamically.

What do I have to do to be able to delete that component?

I tried to unpublish components using the template which is being rendered with the component I am trying to delete, I tried to unpublish the template itself but nothing helped..

1. Component called "New Component" - **trying to delete**, **unpublished**
2. Template of schema called "Dynamic richtext with segmented placeholder" - **rendered with the "New component" above**, **unpublished**
3. Componenet called "Share dynamic" which is using the template of "Dynamic richtext with segmented placeholder" - **unpublished**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: To be sure, what error do you get when trying to delete New Component?

Comment: @AlvinReyes that the component is published and I cant delete published components

Comment: It might be the case that component was published with a CT that no longer exists. If you have access to database you can check the status there...you will also get CT ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a solution (without tridion).
I've added another scheme to the template which was rendered with the component I tried to delete, then I unpulbished the component again and this time it also unpublished to rendered with thing which let me delete the component.
Then I had to unpbulish the template with the extra scheme > remove the scheme and publish the template again.

**EDIT:**

I will write in in a more elegant way:

1. Open the template which was rendered with the problematic component
2. Add any scheme to that template and save.
3. Unpublish the problematic component (this time it will work)
4. Unpublish the template form #1
5. Remove the scheme that you added in #2 from the template
6. Publish the template

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your component is not in fact unpublished, which would prevent it from being deleted. In Tridion components can be added to a page and then that page published, or published directly themselves as a Dynamic Component Presentation. The images you're showing above are of the second option. To delete the component you've shown you'll have to go to the publication they are published from, in this case "06 888Poker_New EN", select the component and unpublish. Make sure when you unpublish that you select all 3 publishing targets shown in your second image. Once you have successfully unpublished this component from all 3 targets refreshing the view of the components in Tridion should show that the globe has disappeared from the component's icon and you should now be ready to unpublish.

Comment: The components rendered with the "New Component" are Component Template, I did unpublish it but it didnt help

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the components are Component Templates. These are two different structures in Tridion. Components contain content, templates are designs and other code that provide instructions on how to render this content. Together a component and the template it is rendered against are a component presentation. In your case you've published this component against a dynamic template creating a dynamic component presentation, which needs to be unpublished. When you followed the instructions in these answers did you see 3 successful unpublishes in the queue?

Comment: Yes, you can see the new image I've uploaded above.

Comment: That looks correct. When you use the Where Used tool and view the published tab does it still show the component as published to the same Target?

Comment: Yes :|, I tried everything I could think of..

Comment: In that case it sounds like something has gotten corrupted with your CM database. You should avoid touching this as it will void your warranty with SDL. From here your best bet is to contact SDL directly for support.

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try Following:

1. Go to the publication "06 888Poker_New EN"
2. Navigate to the "New Component".
3. Un-Publish the component from All the targets
4. Go to the publication, where "New Component" is created.
5. Delete the Component

Comment: That's what I've done.. but it is remain the same...

Comment: Can you confirm, when you unpublish the component. In the publishing queue you get three Transactions one for each publication target as shown in your Image?

Comment: Uploaded another image.

Comment: Okay, it seems its unpublished form all three targets. So it should be deleted. If still a issue, I guess there is something wrong at the CM end. I'd suggest you to reach out to SDL support.

Comment: Alright, thank you!